# Map Composition in Fluent NHibernate

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, composite

There are 2 classes: Product and Image.

1. The Product has only one Image.
2. No orphan Images can exist.

This represent ***composition*** relationship in UML which means:
Assigning Product.Image a newImage results in following

1. delete old image;
2. insert new image;
3. link new image to the product.

Now I need to map it to the RDBMS tables (meta-code):

```
Product (Id primary key, ImageId int references Image(id))  
Image(Id primary key, Content)
```

The question is HOW to do it using Fluent NHibernate.
PLEASE NOTE:

```
productMap.References(x => x.Image).Cascade.All()
```

is not applicable - it DOES NOT delete the orphan image.

Also NH DOES NOT support all-delete-orphan for many-to-one, on-to-one.

I probably need something like join with component...
BUT IN FLUENT NH.

UPDATE: James in FNH user groups suggested this syntax:

```
WithTable("other table", m => 
{
  m.Component(...);
});
```

But no luck with it: NotSupportedException: Obsolete
It supposed to work in v1 (upcomming) of FNH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map like a component ?

Mapping with Fluent : http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/show/StandardMappingComponents

NH doc : http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-component

Comment: Yeah. I probably need a component BUT the it should be in a separate table.  
So I probably need to mix *join* with *component*.  
Do not see how I can do this using FNH.